# Can you use wxMutex in an event handler?

Tags: c++, windows, wxwidgets

Is it possible to use wxMutex->Lock() in an event handler? Since it's the main program thread (gui thread) it can't sleep right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly *can* - it's not going to blow up your computer or melt your hard drive or cause demons to fly out of your nostrils if you try.

That said, doing *anything* on your UI thread that might block is bad, bad, bad, bad, *bad*.

So while you technically *can*, you really *shouldn't*.

Comment: Adding why it is bad might be helpful.

Comment: The UI thread handles all user interaction for your program. If your UI thread is blocked, then the user *cannot* interact with your program - no responding to mouse clicks, no window repainting, *nothing*. Thus, it is critical not to block the UI thread.